# LogScaled BarLegend for Density Histogram

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I am plotting `DensityHistogram`s with a logscaled y-axis with this code:

```
DensityHistogram[wd, {{1}, {50}}, PlotRange -> {{-20, 50}, {Log10[40], Log10[6000]}}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Linear", "Log10"}, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"Energie/q in eV/q"}, {"x in R"}}, 
 LabelStyle -> {"Medium"}, ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", 
 ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", 
 ChartLegends -> BarLegend[{"DarkRainbow", {0, 25}},
  LegendLabel -> Placed["#Ionen", Top]]]
```

My data is weighted so I hope it doesn't make any difference if an example for a row of `wd` is:

```
{47.4237, 1266.92}
```

I recieve a logscaled $y$ axis and a linear $x$ axis. The problem is that my `BarLegend` isn't scaled by `Log10`. Could anyone change my code so I receive a logscaled `BarLegend`? (The label and placement of the label is very important, I hope it is possible without changing that.)  Thank you.

Comment: i dont know if that is useful but for example the values of my barlegend range from 0 to 1000

Answer (score 1):

First, a note about your `BarLegend`: It is generally safer if you just put `Automatic` as specification for the color function an range - that way, those parameters are taken from the Plot and are guaranteed to match: In your case, this means

```
ChartLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, LegendLabel -> Placed["#Ionen", Top]]
```

**Note**: The z specification in `PlotRange` only removes data outside the specified range from the plot - it doesn't rescale the color function to the new maximum, and the legends are left untouched. If you need to customize this further, take a look at [`ColorFunctionScaling`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunctionScaling.html).

#### Actual answer

The colors of the individual cells are the z-axis of your plot. Therefore, if you want to scale the colors in the legend, simply specify `"Log10"` scaling in `ScalingFunctions`:

```
DensityHistogram[wd, {{1}, {50}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-20, 50}, {Log10[40], Log10[6000]}}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Linear", "Log10", "Log10"}, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"Energie/q in eV/q"}, {"x in R"}}, 
 LabelStyle -> {"Medium"}, ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", 
 ChartLegends -> 
  BarLegend[Automatic, LegendLabel -> Placed["#Ionen", Top]]]
```

Produces: (with random data: `Table[{RandomReal[{-20, 50}], RandomReal[3000]}, 10000]`)

[image]

vs. before (same data):

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this perfect answer :)